# Changing Jenkins default repo location

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have setup Jenkinson my machine. Automatically it downloads all the dependencies
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.m2\repository

Now i want to point this to {user_home}.m2 repo.

I tried changing it from Settings.xml with  but it still downloads to systemprofile.m2\repository directly.

Please help me to change this repo location